# Trying to get image scanned but getting same long list error

Tags: php

I am trying to scan a answer sheet and I am getting the list of errors on server as this code is part of batch job process.

my code is:

```
global $CFG;

    //if ($x >= imagesx($this->image) or $x >= imagesy($this->image)) { // point is out of range

    if ($x > imagesx($this->image) or $x > imagesy($this->image)) { 
        return false; 
    }
    $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($this->image, imagecolorat($this->image, $x, $y));
    $gray = $rgb['red'] + $rgb['green'] + $rgb['blue'];

    if ($gray > $this->papergray) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

the error is in line:

```
$rgb = imagecolorsforindex($this->image, imagecolorat($this->image, $x, $y));
```

And error is:

> Notice: imagecolorat(): 1520,-416 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mo d\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1090
>
> Notice: imagecolorat(): 1520,-415 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mo d\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1090
>
> Notice: imagecolorat(): 1520,-416 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mo d\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1090
>
> (Cont ....)

Comment: `-416`. you're trying to get a color at a negative pixel position, which is impossible. GD images have 0,0 at the top left and only ever have positive pixel positions.

Answer (score 2):

Typo:

```
if ($x > imagesx($this->image) or $x > imagesy($this->image)) { 
                                   ^---------^
```

You'd doing width-width/width-height comparisons, instead of width-width/heigh-height.

Most likely if you have `$y` for the indicated var, you'd never get error, as your negative $y would obviously never be larger than the image's height.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check that $x and $y are >0. In the error messages $y is negative.

Comment: Thanks for all of you for your responses. i have no idea about what this code trying to do. i am started looking into code and trying to understand but coudn't pic the error. any further suggestion ? for code part imagecolorat($this->image, $x, $y) as this the source of error.

Comment: Yes and that is because the initial check is not checking all conditions and is also wrong. When x,y are out of range the code should return false and not even try to call imagecolorat().